# i have a invalid argument supplied for foreach() error when passing array variable from controller to view page in laravel,

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

> > this controller controller code. $name contain array of values i have display  name in dropdownlist

```
public function category()
{

    $name =DB::select('select name from category');
   $category = json_encode($name);
   return view('Addworkout')->with('categoryname',$category);

}
```

> this is my view page

```
<select id="select1" class="form-control select2-hidden-accessible" style="width: 100%" data-placeholder=" select category" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">

                  <?php foreach($categoryname as $cate) { ?>
                  <option value="" disable selected><?php echo $cate->name; ?></option>

                   <?php } ?>
                </select>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you do

```
$category = json_encode($name);
```

you're serializing the results of the query into a string, which is indeed an invalid argument for a **foreach loop**.

Why are you doing so?